# Searching for exact word match in MySQL column values

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am working with a MySQL database and have a table with a column named "Tags" that contains multiple tags combined in a single string. For example, a row in the "Tags" column might in figure below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Ibz.png)

I want to perform a search that retrieves rows where the "Tags" column contains an exact match for a specific tag, such as "ios", but excludes rows with variations like "IOS" or "ios2".

I have tried using the LIKE operator, but it gives me matches for partial substrings, and the results are not case-sensitive. I also attempted to use the BINARY keyword, but it only works for exact matches when the column contains only the tag I'm searching for.

Is there a way to perform a case-sensitive exact word match in the "Tags" column? I need the query to return rows with exactly the tag I'm searching for, and exclude any variations with additional characters.

Comment: Check your edit history, I'm tired trying to fix your formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default MySQL defines `VARCHAR` columns as case insensitive. You can make them case sensitive by explicitly setting an appropriate collation, such as `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`. The suffix `cs` denotes a case sensitive collation. Multiple collations are case insensitive, depending on your needs.

For example:

```
create table t (
  tags varchar(100) collate utf8mb4_0900_as_cs
);

insert into t (tags) values
  ('<abc><def>'),
  ('<abc><ghi>'), 
  ('<def><GHI>'), 
  ('<abc><def><ghi>');

select * from t where tags like '%<ghi>%';
```

Result:

```
tags
---------------
<abc><ghi>
<abc><def><ghi>
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NmXf5Qeq).

Comment: `_bin` is everything-sensitive.